# Simple nested while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Highly appreciate if somebody can give a simple explanation of why in code 1 big 'X' is printed multiple times but not in code 2. Only difference is in the break statement?

> Code 1

```
flag=False
i=0
while not flag:
    print(f"big {i}")
    while True:
        i+=1
        print(i)
        if i==5:
            flag=True
            print("cond reached")
        break
```

Output

big 0
1
big 1
2
big 2
3
big 3
4
big 4
5
cond reached

> Code 2

```
flag=False
i=0
while not flag:
    print(f"big {i}")
    while True:
        i+=1
        print(i)
        if i==5:
            flag=True
            print("cond reached")
            break
```

Output

big 0
1
2
3
4
5
cond reached

Comment: do you know how `break` works in a loop because that is exactly the reason why they differ

Comment: Your break is in the `if` clause in the second code, meaning it only runs when `i=5`, so the outer loop is only called once since when `i=5`, `flag=True`

Comment: Note that removing the `while True:` loop in your first example doesn't change it, since it always `break`s on its first iteration.  If you remove that inner loop (and the `break`), is it clearer what the code is doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second segment, the `break` statement is only executed when `i=5`, so the code is stuck in the inner loop until i = 5.  When this happens, the flag is set to `True`, which means that the outer loop isn't executed again.   In other words:

In the first segment of code, the outer while loop is called multiple times because the inner loop always breaks, whereas, in the second segment of code, the outer while loop is only called once because the inner loop only breaks when `i=5`, which also sets the breaking condition for the outer loop.